# How to write Elasticsearch DSL multi field and multi term query?

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

How should I write an Elasticsearch (6.6) DSL query to return only documents Doc2 and Doc3 from this example pool:

```
Doc1 { "Field1" : "Term1", "Field2" : "Term2" }
Doc2 { "Field1" : "Term6", "Field2" : "Term2" }
Doc3 { "Field1" : "Term6", "Field2" : "Term5" }
Doc4 { "Field1" : "Term3", "Field2" : "Term1" }
```

**Query logic**: (Field1 or Field2) are not equal to (Term1 or Term2 or Term3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming datatype of `Field1` and `Field2` is keyword you can make use of should and must_not clause of [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/query-dsl-bool-query.html) with [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/query-dsl-terms-query.html) to get the desired result.

Query will look as below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "Field1": [
                    "Term1",
                    "Term2",
                    "Term3"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "Field2": [
                    "Term1",
                    "Term2",
                    "Term3"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Liudas Glad it worked. Please upvote and accept the answer.